# Perl: Regex for reading a log statement

Tags: regex, perl

I have logs coming in the following way:

```
2013-07-10 17:27:08 +0900 app.log.error.traffic: {"app.log_count":10,"app.log_bytes":9960,"app.log_count_rate":0.5,"app.log_bytes_rate":166.0}
```

The "app.log.error.traffic" part will not change but the dates and other numbers change all the time. In other words, "2013-07-10" changes everyday, "08 +0900" can also change, "app.log.error.traffic:" doesn't, and ""app.log_count"" also doesn't change.

I want to make a perl script that raises a warning if the number next to "app.log_count": goes beyond a threshold level.

I made the following:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env perl         
 use strict;
 use warnings; 
 use utf8;

 my $file_location = "/var/log/app.log" ; 
 my $threshold = 3;        

 open my $infile, "<", $file_location or die("$!: $file_location");
    while (<$infile>) {
      if (/ REGEX /) {
          if ($_ >= $threshold) {
          # warning
          } else {
          # not warning;
          }
      }
  }    

close $infile;
```

But as you see, the most important part is missing. What shall I put in REGEX ?

Comment: `my $file_location = ; 
 my $threshold = ;    ` is wrong

Comment: Find a tutorial on regex, a basic one should be able to teach you how to use the regex and if it's failing, update your question.

Comment: @Paulchenkiller I added an example

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    my ($value) = $_=~ /"app.log_count":(\d+)/;
    print"$value\n"; # will give you 10
}

__DATA__
013-07-10 17:27:08 +0900 app.log.error.traffic: {"app.log_count":10,"app.log_bytes":9960,"app.log_count_rate":0.5,"app.log_bytes_rate":166.0}
```

Comment: thanks this "app.log_count":(\d+) regex seems to be matching

Comment: Don't need `$_=~`, and `app.log` should be `app\.log`, but I'm just nitpicking.