# Perl: How to make Perl remember the last line it read?

Tags: perl

There is this big log file changing almost every second with lines like the following:

```
013-07-10 17:59:08 +0900 "app.log_count":0,"
013-07-10 17:59:09 +0900 "app.log_count":4,"
013-07-10 17:59:10 +0900 "app.log_count":1,"
013-07-10 17:59:12 +0900 "app.log_count":5,"
```

I'm making a script that reads this log. Specifically, it tries to check if the "app.log_count" part goes beyond a certain threshold:

```
open my $infile, "<", $file_location or die("$!: $file_location");
    while (<$infile>) {
      if ( "app.log_count":(\d+) ) {
          if ($_ >= $threshold) {
          # warning
          } else {
          # not warning;
          }
      }
  }    
close $infile;
```

Which I'm planning to run every minute as a cron job.

But I want to make a script that does not run the whole file every time. If the script reads all the log file every minute, and we assume that at minute t there is a regex mach, it will send a mail notification; then at minute t+1 when the script runs again, it will send another mail notification even though there hasn't been a "new match".

So I need to make a **script that remembers the last position (line) it read,** so the next time, it starts reading from that position. Any ideas? All the best, Adrian.

Comment: Use tell() and seek()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: Regex for reading a log statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566296/perl-regex-for-reading-a-log-statement)

Comment: Perhaps [`File::Tail`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ATail) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I wrote with your help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use File::Tail;
_check_log();

sub _check_log {
  my $log_dir       = "";
  my $log_name      = "";
  my $file_location = $log_dir . $log_name;
  my $threshold     = 10;

  my $infile = File::Tail->new(
    name        => $file_location,
    maxinterval => 300,
  );

  while ( defined( my $line = $infile->read ) ) {
    if ( $line =~ m{"app.log_count":(\d+)} && $1 ) {
      if ( $1 >= $threshold ) {
        _log_warn( $1 );
      }
    }
  }
}

sub _log_warn {

  # Stuff you wanna have done when there are too many errors
}
```